# Download File To Server With PHP then separating the contents of the file

Tags: php

I'll give a really detailed basis to my question.

To start off, I am trying to create a clan lookup using the RuneScape Highscore API.

To generate the list of users in a particular clan, you would need to go to this site: http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-hiscores/members_lite.ws?clanName=X

Once going to this site, it will initiate a download for a .ws file. When opened, it is seperated by commas, thus looking like this:

```
Clanmate, Clan Rank, Total XP, Kills
Kol,Owner,214278437,10
Biteem,Deputy Owner,709189979,39
KitKatKiller,Deputy Owner,267880637,1
Spooky,Deputy Owner,692887397,773
Ghost Team,Overseer,1333197602,323
Yamilla,Overseer,1873041891,56
```

To state what I want to do, is I want the user to type in a name of a clan, then when they hit submit, for it to download the file to MY file server, then display the contents of the .ws file but disregarding everything but the Clanmate column.

So for instance if the user typed in the Clan Name "maxed" I want it to show:

```
Kol
Biteem
KitKat
Spooky
Ghost Team
Yamilla
```

I have a starting point php code however I don't know how to download the file, or to seperate each content of the .ws file then to display all of those names on the page.

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if ($_POST['submit']) {

  //This should be changed to downloading the file to the file server
  //But this is the format that the link should be. 
  header('Location: http://services.runescape.com/m=clan-hiscores 
  /members_lite.ws?clanName='.$_POST['clanname']);

  } 


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to write code if you don't have any but I have some suggestions which should help you to write this script.
To download file from url you can use php function file_get_contents and after that to get values as array I will recommend to use str_getcsv.